# nodejs childprocess.spawn error event not occuring instead of exit

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I'm purposely trying to stderr from my childProcess but its resolving to code 1 on exit. The command I'm using should fail to remove directory and it should reject promise from childProcess.stderr.on() but its reaching childProcess.on('exit',()). What is wrong here?

```
  const path = require('path')
  const { spawn } = require('child_process');
 
  function removeDir(fullPath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const childProcess = spawn('rm', ['-f', fullPath]);
 
      childProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
      });
 
      childProcess.stderr.on('error', (error) => {
        //console.error('Error executing command:', data.toString());
       reject(error);
      });
 
      childProcess.on('exit', (code) => {
        if (code === 0) {
          console.log('im here')
          resolve(code);
        } else {
          reject(new Error(`Child process exited with code ${code}`));
        }
      });
    });
  }
 
  async function execute() {
    try {
      await removeDir('/Users/.../rmv_dir');
      console.log('Directory removed successfully');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error: ', err);
   }
```

```
 Expected
 Error: rm: rmv_dir: is a directory  
  Output
  Error:  Error: Child process exited with code 1

    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/.../tests/setupAndTeardown.js:23:16)

    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)

    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
```

Comment: does `childProcess` exit? in that case `childProcess.on('exit',...` will be executed (regardless if you reject the promise elsewhere, that has no bearing on `exit` event)

Comment: If you want to delete a directory you need to use `-rf` and not `-f` (so it should be `spawn('rm', ['-f', fullPath])`)